# How to decompose a matrix as the sum of Kronecker products?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, matrix-decomposition, kronecker-product

I encounter a problem revalent to Kronecker product (KP).

I want to decompose $A=\sum^r_{i=1}B_i\otimes C_i$, where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{8\times2}, B_i\in \mathbb{R}^{4\times2}, C_i\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times1}.$

I note that some matrices can be decomposed as a single KP $(r=1)$.

like,
$A_1=\begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\1& 0\\0& 1\\0& 1\\1& 0\\1& 0\\0& 1\\0& 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\0& 1\\1& 0\\0& 1\end{bmatrix}\otimes\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

However, there are also many matrices need the sum of more than one KPs $(r>1)$.

like,
$A_2=\begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\0& 0\\0& 1\\0& 0\\1& 0\\1& 0\\0& 1\\0& 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\0& 1\\0& 0\\0& 0\end{bmatrix}\otimes\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0& 0\\0& 0\\1& 0\\0& 1\end{bmatrix}\otimes\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

I know the above examples can be decomposed to a more number of the sum of KPs, but my question is how to decompose a matrix as the sum of KPs with  **least $r$**.

Remark: $A$, and the size of $B_i$ and $C_i$ are known; $B_i$, $C_i$, $r$ are unknown and expected to be solved.

Comment: @Jean Marie. Yes, there are infinitely many KPs. But any feasible one is fine to me. My focus is on how to determine the least r. I edit my last sentence to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: You can view $B$ and $C$ as vectors in spaces of dimension $8$ and $2$ respectively. Rather than considering the Kronecker product, you can instead consider the outer product of $B$ and $C$, denoted by $\circ$. Then $B \circ C$ is a matrix of size $8 \times 2$ and the $r$ you are interested in is the same as the rank of that matrix. Note that $B \circ C$ is not necessarily the same as your original matrix. This is easier to see if you let $B$ be $4 \times 1$ and let $C$ be $2 \times 2$. Now  $B$ and $C$ are both viewed as vectors of length $4$, so $B \circ C$ is a matrix of size $4 \times 4$.

Comment: The main point is that you can transform your problem into a question about matrix decompositions. This illustrates that after transforming A to appropriate space you can compute the rank and decomposition of A using the SVD for example.

Comment: @Eric. I guess what you mean is to vectorize B and C. Then use $rank( vec(B) \circ vec(C))$ to compute the least $r$. But I don't know $B$ and $C$ at the beginning. In my problem, the known are $A$ and the size of $B_i$ and $C_i$, the unknown are $B_i$ and $C_i$ and $r$.

Comment: Why do I have to transform $A$ to another space to compute the rank? @Eric

Comment: Take a look at Nikos Pitsianis 1997 [PhD dissertation](https://www.proquest.com/openview/d9527b2b50fa20d2b7c866debe27e5dc/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=18750&diss=y). He addresses this question and even provides Matlab  code to calculate the decomposition.  He also co-authored some papers on this topic with Charles van Loan at around this same time.

Comment: @greg. Thanks so much for your recommended reference.

Comment: I'm a bit late to respond so perhaps the question is already addressed. While you don't know $A$ and $B$, you can figure out what $A$ gets mapped to under this transformation without knowing $B$ and $C$, the only important thing is the dimensions. As for why you need the transformation, this I meant to illustrate with the second example where $A$ will be a $4 \times 4$ matrix. This means that you expect $A$ to have rank $4$ w.r.t that tensor structure. Of course, an $8 \times 2$ matrix cannot have rank $2$, so if you want to use matrix operations, a transformation is necessary.

Comment: Also related: The Kronecker Product SVD (KPSVD) by van Loan, see, e.g., here: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/KSVD.pdf

Answer (score 3):

For a fixed matrix $C$, a Kronecker product of the form $B\otimes C$ is just any block matrix where each block is a scalar multiple of $C$ (the scalars being the entries of $B$).  So, to write a matrix $A$ as a sum of Kronecker products $\sum_{i=1}^r B_i\otimes C_i$, the $C_i$ must be a collection of matrices that span all the $C$-shaped blocks in $A$, and then the $B_i$ are just the coefficients you use to write each $C$-shaped block as a linear combination of the $C_i$.  In your case, $C$ is $2\times 1$ so the space of all possible $C$-shaped blocks is only $2$-dimensional, so you always have $r\leq 2$.

Explicitly, using $r=2$, you can always just take $C_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $C_2=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.  Then $B_1$ and $B_2$ will just be the submatrices of $A$ formed by its odd and even rows, respectively.  If one of $B_1$ and $B_2$ happens to be a scalar multiple of the other (say $B_2=aB_1$), then you can simplify $A=B_1\otimes C_1+B_2\otimes C_2$ down to just $B_1\otimes (C_1+aC_2)$ and get a solution with $r=1$.  (In terms of the description in the previous paragraph, this is the case where every $2\times 1$ block in $A$ is a scalar multiple of $C_1+aC_2=\begin{bmatrix}1\\a\end{bmatrix}$, so there is a single matrix that spans all the $2\times 1$ blocks of $A$.)

Comment: Your comments are inspirational. As you have stated, $r$ is no more than the dimension of $C$. In case $C$ is a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{m_c\times n_c}$,  could I say $r \leq m_c\times n_c$?

Comment: @fibon Indeed you can always achieve $r\le m_c n_c$ when $C$ is a $m_c\times n_c$ matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is possible with at most $2$ components but not with the dimensions you need.

Indeed, the Singular Values Decomposition [SVD](https://personal.utdallas.edu/%7Eherve/Abdi-SVD2007-pretty.pdf):

$$A=U \Sigma V^T$$

where:

$$ U:=(U_1|U_2|...|U_8) \ \text{is} \  8 \times 8$$

$$V:=(V_1|V_2)  \ \text{is} \   8 \times 2$$

$$\Sigma:=diag(\underbrace{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,0,0...0)}_{8 \ \text{terms}}$$

can be written under the following form:

$$A=\underbrace{\sigma_1 U_1}_{B_1}\underbrace{V_1}_{C_1}+\underbrace{\sigma_2 U_2}_{B_2}\underbrace{V_2}_{C_2}$$

$$A=B_1 \otimes C_1 +B_2 \otimes C_2$$

Comment: In fact, I have now written the solution for the $8 \times 2$ case using the SVD in replacement of the eigendecomposition which, evidently, doesn't makes sense for the non-square case (where had I my head ?)

Comment: But now $B_i$ and $C_i$ aren't $4\times 2$ and $2\times 1$.

Comment: Yes, it is what I said at the beginning : "not the dimensions you need".

Comment: It also also possible with at most two components in the dimensions asked for.